# Intermittent instances of 0 byte file downloads

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-server-2012

I've been having issues lately with a VBScript that will download files from an FTP server. It's been working ok for some years, but recently it's been downloading 0-byte files, they're just empty. This should never be the case.

In troubleshooting, I tried downloading a batch of files using the FTP command in CMD, and a different set of files were downloaded that were 0 bytes. (Btw, this is why I didn't add WINSCP and VBScript tags). Upon re-attempting the download of these empty files, I notice they download ok without issue, they come with data. What could be the issue here? What else can I try? Specifically, while keeping the OS, as I do not really have control over this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the download code into a loop, and in each iteration confirmed the file's existence and size by calling a function, and passing it the filename. Doing this allows me to log more and see that the 0-byte downloads happen more often than I thought.